# OpenCL : Write to an existing cl::Buffer?

Tags: opencl

I happen to have a library that already gives me a GPU Ptr in OpenCL internally.

```
auto* gpuImagePtr = upImpl->upCaffeNet->blobs().at(0)->mutable_gpu_data();
cl::Buffer imageBuffer = cl::Buffer((cl_mem)gpuImagePtr);
```

I want to write data into the pointer pointed by imageBuffer, without allocating new memory. How would I actually do that? If I instantiate a cl::Buffer, it will simply write a new address. I don't want to write a kernel to do this.

In CUDA I would do this

```
auto* gpuImagePtr = upImpl->upCaffeNet->blobs().at(0)->mutable_gpu_data();
cudaMemcpy(gpuImagePtr, inputData.getConstPtr(), inputData.getVolume() * sizeof(float),
                               cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

In OpenCL, I tried doing this but it just segfaults:

```
auto* gpuImagePtr = upImpl->upCaffeNet->blobs().at(0)->mutable_gpu_data();
cl::Buffer imageBuffer = cl::Buffer((cl_mem)gpuImagePtr);
op::CLManager::getInstance(upImpl->mGpuId)->getQueue().enqueueWriteBuffer(imageBuffer, true, 0, inputData.getVolume() * sizeof(float), inputData.getConstPtr());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, it turns out I need to use the retain flag:

```
cl::Buffer imageBuffer = cl::Buffer((cl_mem)gpuImagePtr, true);
```

Now it doesn't crash anymore